# why I can't comment out my SCSS snippet while it generates CSS code properly?

Tags: css, sass

I'm implementing a customized CSS library with SCSS and in my media query section I forgot to add `semicolon` between my `@media`'s but it generated the codes in CSS correctly and it's just working fine, the problem is when I wanted to comment out one of my `@media`'s It just didn't happen and threw an error and I couldn't comment it.

so I was wondering what's the logic behind this adding `semicolon` at the end of the `@media`, if it's absence is harmless why I cant comment my `@media` and if it presence is essential why I'm generating my CSS code without any problem while I'm not using any `semicolon`.

P.n: The first snippet below is for showing I haven't used any `semicolon`, the second one is to show even I haven't used `semicolon` it generates CSS code properly.

code:

```
//breakpoints.scss

$breakpoint: (
"xs":0,
"s":480px,
"md":720px,
"lg":960px,
"xl":1200px,
"xxl":1300px
)!default;

@mixin xs {
@media (min-width:map-get($breakpoint, "xs")) and (max-width:map-get($breakpoint, "s")) {
    @content
}
}

@mixin s {
@media (min-width:map-get($breakpoint, "s")) and (max-width:map-get($breakpoint, "md")) {
    @content
}
 }

@mixin md {
@media (min-width:map-get($breakpoint, "md")) and (max-width:map-get($breakpoint, "lg")) {
    @content
}
}

@mixin lg {
@media (min-width:map-get($breakpoint, "lg")) and (max-width:map-get($breakpoint, "xl")) {
    @content
}
 }

@mixin xl {
@media (min-width:map-get($breakpoint, "xl")) and (max-width:map-get($breakpoint,"xxl")) {
    @content
}
 }

@mixin xxl {
@media (min-width:map-get($breakpoint, "xxl")){
    @content
}
}
```

```
//grid.scss

$gridColumns: 12 !default;
@include breakpoints.xs {
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .col-#{$i}-xs {
        width: math.div($i * 100%, $gridColumns);
    }
} 
}

@include breakpoints.s {
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .col-#{$i}-s {
        width: math.div($i * 100%, $gridColumns);
    }
}
  }

@include breakpoints.md {
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .col-#{$i}-md {
        width: math.div($i * 100%, $gridColumns);
    }
}
 }

@include breakpoints.lg {
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .col-#{$i}-lg {
        width: math.div($i * 100%, $gridColumns);
    }
}
 }

@include breakpoints.xl {
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .col-#{$i}-xl {
        width: math.div($i * 100%, $gridColumns);
    }
  }
 }

@include breakpoints.xxl{
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .col-#{$i}-xxl {
        width: math.div($i * 100%, $gridColumns);
}
}
 }
```

Comment: The code works just fine. Please post an example of your code when it doesn't work.

Comment: I found out the problem, when I comment my **@media**, then I can't access it in **@include** in gride.scss stylesheet, so the error was related to that part, but what confused me was semicolon, when I don't add semicolon to the end of my **@media** and I try to comment **@media** it doesn't change the color of commented section to gray or anything else and the color is constant, so I thought the problem is semicolon but actually the problem is struggle to access something which is commented in another stylesheet.@Wezelkrozum

Comment: the lack of changing color in commented section due to not using the semicolon is the question, why is this happening? why the commented section color doesn't change into gray or any other color and instead it just remains the same?@Wezelkrozum